# How to rearrange and delete file names

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rename

I am trying to delete random numbers in my file names in cmd (Ubuntu).

What I want to do is:

279796_3D AXL MPR_26438044_0001.dcm —> 279796_3D AXL MPR_0001.dcm

279796_3D AXL MPR_26438446_0011.dcm —> 279796_3D AXL MPR_0011.dcm

Also, is there a way to do it in python?

I was planning to rearrange the random numbers to the back of the file name and then delete those numbers all together. But I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the perl-based file-rename (from Ubuntu package `rename`):

```
$ rename -n 's/_\d+_/_/' *.dcm
rename(279796_3D AXL MPR_26438044_0001.dcm, 279796_3D AXL MPR_0001.dcm)
rename(279796_3D AXL MPR_26438446_0011.dcm, 279796_3D AXL MPR_0011.dcm)
```

Using `mmv`:

```
$ mmv -n '*_*_*_*.dcm' '#1_#2_#4.dcm'
279796_3D AXL MPR_26438044_0001.dcm -> 279796_3D AXL MPR_0001.dcm
279796_3D AXL MPR_26438446_0011.dcm -> 279796_3D AXL MPR_0011.dcm
```

Remove the `-n` once you are satisfied that it is going to do the right thing.

Using the bash shell, with KSH-style extended globbing:

```
$ shopt -s extglob

$ for f in *.dcm; do echo mv -n -- "$f" "${f/_+([0-9])_/_}"; done
mv -n -- 279796_3D AXL MPR_26438044_0001.dcm 279796_3D AXL MPR_0001.dcm
mv -n -- 279796_3D AXL MPR_26438446_0011.dcm 279796_3D AXL MPR_0011.dcm
```

Here, remove the `echo` once you are satisfied that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: Thanks!! The first option solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

We can rename files in bulk in **python3**
using the `re` and `pathlib` modules.

```
python3 -c 'import re, pathlib
for f in pathlib.Path(".").glob("*.dcm"):
  f.rename(re.sub(r"_\d+(?=_)","",f.name))
'
```

Answer (score 0):

A call to `cut` should do the trick:

```
cut -d_ -f-2,4-
```

test it with :

```
echo "279796_MPR_26438044_0001.dcm" | cut -d_ -f-2,4-
```

Using it to rename a bunch of file become:

```
for f in *.dcm; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | cut -d_ -f-2,4-)"; done
```

`cut` split the word each occurrence of delimiter `_` (`-d _`) and print the field from the first to the second (`-f-2`) and from the fourth to the last (`,-4-`).

Comment: I just realized there was a space between the names, so is there another way to do it?

Comment: It works the same.

Comment: I am using the last option, but it says 'No such file or directory'.                          "for f in [0-9]*_3D AXL MPR_[0-9]*_[0-9]*.dcm; do mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | cut -d_ -f-2,4-); done"       This is what I used.

Comment: You would also need to quote the command substitution `"$(echo "$f" | cut -d_ -f-2,4-)"` in the case of names with spaces

Comment: Yep @steeldriver! I miss it, thanks!